# Browser-sync doesn't reload the page on watch tasks completion

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify

My watch task is like:

```
const select = {
   js: './src/components/**/*.js',
   scss: [
    './src/global/**/*.scss',
    './src/components/**/*.scss'
  ],
  html: [
    './src/components/**/*.cshtml',
    './src/components/**/*.html'
  ]
};

gulp.task('watch', () => {
  gulp.watch(select.js, ['scripts']);
  gulp.watch(select.scss, ['styles']);
  gulp.watch(select.cshtml, ['views']);
});
```

My style task is like:

```
const scssForCompile = [
  './src/global/scss/style.scss'
];

gulp.task('styles', () => {
  return gulp.src(scssForCompile)
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(autoprefixer())
    .pipe(cleancss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/styles'))
    .pipe(browsersync.reload({stream: true}));
});
```

Please note scssForCompile  is different from select.scss. Every time I edit any file the associated asset files are getting updated - no problem so far. The only issue is that I don't get reload every times my asset files are getting updated.

I am assuming

```
.pipe(browsersync.reload({stream: true}));
```

should do the trick but it doesn't. Can someone please help to get the page reload using browserify when my asset file is updated?

[code on git hub](https://github.com/neginbasiri/gulpsetup)

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong with your gulpfile. You need to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @SvenSchoenung thanks for the reply. I created a git hub repo for it you can find link https://github.com/neginbasiri/gulpsetup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're working with two different instances of `browsersync`.

In **tasks/styles.js** you require the default instance:

```
const browsersync = require('browser-sync');
```

However in **tasks/server.js** you create a *new* instance using `create()`:

```
const browsersync = require('browser-sync').create();
```

So when you do `.pipe(browsersync.reload({stream: true}))` in **tasks/styles.js** you're trying to notify a `browsersync` instance that isn't actually running.

You need to change your **tasks/server.js** to use the default instance as well:

```
const browsersync = require('browser-sync');
```